# How to fetch data from active directory in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new to SharePoint 2013.

I want to fetch data from active directory to the column of custom list without using visual studio (only SharePoint designer is allowed to use) .

Is there any way to do this...?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any direct way to do this. But there's indirect way, which using sql server linked server to fetch active directory to be imported to a sql table. You then can promote the table as SharePoint external Lists.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/